# Merge 2 .jks truststore files

Tags: java, security, keytool, jks

I am using a Tomcat that is SSL enabled, using truststores for client authentication.

I have two .jks trustore files.

The first, I use it for the PROD environment and the other for the TEST environment client certificates.

I deploy the web application, on a Tomcat and until now i was setting one of the above files in the  configuration (according to the environment).

Is it possible i can merge those files into one .jks truststore that will accept client certificates both for PROD and TEST environments?

I need to mention that i have the passwords for both truststores.

Thanks!

Answer (score 49):

You can use the `-importkeystore` option of keytool to import an entry from one keystore/truststore to another:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore test.jks -destkeystore common.jks -srcalias myRootCA -destalias myRootCA_TEST -srcstorepass **** -deststorepass ****
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore prod.jks -destkeystore common.jks -srcalias myRootCA -destalias myRootCA_PROD -srcstorepass **** -deststorepass ****
```

The common.jks will then contain both CA to validate the client certificates. However, the application may also need to be reconfigured.

Comment: Each keystore will have it's own private key. What will happen to these keys after merging ?

Comment: Note to myself: the default keystore password is **changeit**

Comment: @KrsnaChaitanya The destination keystore/truststore password will prevail. You can use that to view contents of that.