# Apache HTTP client - How to load multiple key-stores?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I am using Apache http client in my Java project.

I am able to load the ssl keystore and truststore for a single route.

Here's the code snippet I am using:

```
protected void initConnectionManager(HttpClientProps props) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException, CertificateException, IOException {
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = createConnectionManager(buildRegistry(props));
    connectionManager.setMaxTotal(props.getMaxThreadPool());
    connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(props.getDefaultMaxPerRoute());
    setConnManager(connectionManager);
}

protected Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> buildRegistry(HttpClientProps props) throws KeyStoreException, IOException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException {
    final RegistryBuilder<ConnectionSocketFactory> registryBuilder;
    if (props.isSslEnabled()) {
        final KeyStore ts = getKeyStoreInstance(), ks = getKeyStoreInstance();
        ts.load(new FileInputStream(props.getTrustStorePath()), props.getTrustStoreKey().toCharArray());
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(props.getKeyStorePath()), props.getKeyStoreKey().toCharArray());
        final SSLContext ssl = buildSslContext(props, ts, ks);
        final ConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionFactory = getSslConnectionFactory(ssl);
        registryBuilder = createRegistryBuilder(HTTPS, sslConnectionFactory);
    } else {
        registryBuilder = createRegistryBuilder(HTTP, new PlainConnectionSocketFactory());
    }
    return registryBuilder.build();
}

protected RegistryBuilder<ConnectionSocketFactory> createRegistryBuilder(String id, ConnectionSocketFactory factory) {
    return RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create().register(id, factory);
}

protected SSLContext buildSslContext(HttpClientProps props, KeyStore ts, KeyStore ks) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
    return SSLContexts.custom()
            .loadTrustMaterial(ts, this::getTrustStrategy)
            .loadKeyMaterial(ks, props.getKeyStoreKey().toCharArray())
            .setSecureRandom(new SecureRandom())
            .build();
}
```

Now I am trying to figure out for multiple routes for example:

1. https://route1.com/path
2. https://route2.com/path

If both the routes need different keystore JKS and truststore JKS
then how do I set that in the same client and configure it to use keystore1 and truststore1 for route1 and keystore2 and truststore2 for route2?

Or should I use a new object of the httpclient for each route and set the keystore and truststore respectively? [In this approach the catch is a new thread pool will be created for each client. I am trying to avoid it.]

Comment: "Or should I use a new object of the httpclient for each route and set the keystore and truststore respectively?" - or one keystore and one truststore holding all the keymaterials for all the routes. What problem would be solved by having an individual keystore/truststore for each route?

Comment: @Gimby - I have separate keystore and truststore JKS files for both the routes. I see a way provided in this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912067/merge-2-jks-truststore-files to merge the jks certs. Will try this out.